# Jquery get content with ajax and appendTo id

Tags: jquery, ajax, appendto

I load a second page with ajax and want to append a specific id from that page onto the current page.

```
function Content() {
    $("ul.tabs li a").click(function() {
    $.ajax({ 
        url: $(this).attr('href'),
        success: function(response) {
            $(response).find('ul#image-gallery-items').appendTo('ul#image-gallery-items');
        }
    });
    return false;
    })
}
```

what am I missing?

Comment: What's not working? _"what am I missing?"_ a lot of info in the question...

Comment: you're appending an `ul` as a direct child of another/same `ul` ? Did you mean `$(response).find('ul#image-gallery-items li')` instead ?

Comment: @F.Calderan. It's the same id. missing info...

Comment: Oh sorry :D.. well I´m getting the request but it wont append it.. notting happnens :P

Comment: I tried this: $("#image-gallery-items").html($(response).find("#image-gallery-items").children()); but that just gave me an empty <ul></ul>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also load page fragments with jQuery [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function:

```
$("ul.tabs li a").click(function() {
    $('#image-gallery-items').load(this.href + ' #image-gallery-items');
    return false;
})​
```

In this case to *append* elements you can use:

```
$("ul.tabs li a").click(function() {
    $('<div></div>').load(this.href + ' #image-gallery-items').children().appendTo('#image-gallery-items');
    return false;
})​
```

Comment: Thx but I need to do it the $.ajax way

Comment: (I have things binded to the ajax function.. eg loader image etc etc..)